# customize colors of level in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, themes

I would like as said in the title customize colors of the differents levels in org-mode. I have tried from the `customize-group` menu then `org-face` but it looks like I can't change colors there.
So, I've to do it manually but what shall I add in my .init.el file ?
I've added the package color-theme and tried smth like this :

```
 (org-level-1 ((t (:foreground "yellow"))))
```

but I get the follwing error :

> Symbol's function definition is void: org-level-1

Unfortunateley I'm quite new to debugging with Emacs...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, but I don't have time to track it down...

Answer (score 6):

I think your main problem here is actually you do not consider org-level-1 the face but org-level-1 the function (which is not existing as the error message indicates it). You can use something like that to customize in your init file

```el
(custom-theme-set-faces 'user
                        `(org-level-1 ((t (:foreground "yellow")))))
```

Comment: my/org-mode-hook (above) didn't work for me, but this one did!

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the colours of different levels with the following steps:

```
M-x customize <RET>
```

Then in the search box, enter `org level 1` and hit `Search` button. Then you can see `Org level 1 face` through `Org level 8 face`. Expand the nodes you want to modify and set the attributes as you want.

Don't forget to save the result with `Save for future session`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a your own hook for org-mode. That way you could set multiple faces inside the hook and they will all be loaded after org-mode.

```
(defun my/org-mode-hook ()
  "My `org-mode' hook"
  (set-face-attribute org-level-1 nil :foreground "yellow")
  (set-face-attribute org-level-2 nil :foreground "blue"))  ; just add to the list

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my/org-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Consider using an `(eval-after-load "org" '(progn . . .))` statement instead of putting this on the `org-mode-hook` -- the latter potentially gets called a zillion times each Emacs session (e.g., every time an `org-mode` buffer is created), whereas the former will only do this customization/setup one time.  Once its done, its done -- no need to do it more than one time per Emacs session.

Comment: And consider setting the second argument of `set-face-attribute` to `nil` (instead of `t`) so that it applies to **all** frames (existing frames, and also future new frames).  See the doc-string for `set-face-attribute`.

Comment: @lawlist I have the second argument set as `nil` in my own config, though I was mirroring @loukios own choice of `t`, I'll change it in the anwser.

Comment: If using a theme, would you need to insure it is loaded before org-mode when using the `eval-after-load` method? Some themes modify the face attributes of org-mode.

Comment: There have been a lot of inquiries over the past year about the non-existence of a hook that runs after a theme loads, and the last I checked, there was still no such hook.  A user named *pkkm* has added a hook to `load-theme` using `defadvice`:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4v7tcj/does_emacs_have_a_hook_for_when_the_theme_changes/?st=isnecsgg&sh=c293bc40  `(defvar after-load-theme-hook nil "Hook run after a color theme is loaded using 'load-theme'.") (defadvice load-theme (after run-after-load-theme-hook activate) "Run 'after-load-theme-hook'." (run-hooks 'after-load-theme-hook))`